# Reordering DataFrame Columns to Match Another DataFrame's Sort Order in R

Tags: r, sorting, frame

I have two data frames df1 and df2 containing three columns L, M, and G.

```
df1 <- data.frame(L= c(0, 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), M= c(0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3), G= (1:10))
df2<- data.frame(L=c(0,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3), M= c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3), G= c(12, 13, 4, 6, 7, 54, 87,56,3,0))
```

Keeping the df1 as it is with no changes. But, I want to reshuffle the L and M of df2 to be the same sort as df1,  while keeping the corresponding values of G in df2 intact
I want to get the following results

```
desired_result <- data.frame(L= c(0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), M= c(0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3), G= c(12,13,7,4,54,56,6,87,3,0))
```

Comment: If we know that `df1$L` is in sorted order (which is the case in the question) then `dplyr::arrange(df2, L)` or `o <- order(df2$L); df2[o, ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple join after removing the `G` column from `df1`.

```
library(dplyr)
  
df1 %>% select(-G) %>% left_join(df2, join_by(L, M)) 

#   L M  G
#1  0 0 12
#2  1 0 13
#3  1 1  7
#4  2 0  4
#5  2 1 54
#6  2 2 56
#7  3 0  6
#8  3 1 87
#9  3 2  3
#10 3 3  0
```

Equivalent in base R :

```
indx <- match('G', names(df1))
merge(df1[-indx], df2, all.x = TRUE, by = c("L", "M"))
```

Comment: This deliver an error `Error in select(., -G) : unused argument (-G)`

Comment: You might have conflict with `select` function. Try using `dplyr::select` instead.